# Large negative output in C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I need to write a program that stores 5 floating-point numbers to a file, then write a second that will read those numbers and display them. I am using C++ Microsoft visual studio express 2012.

Here is program 1:

```
// This program obtains 5 floating point numbers from the user,
// then saves these numbers to a file.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Define Variables
double num1;    
double num2;    
double num3;    
double num4;    
double num5;        

ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("homework3.txt");

// Get 5 floating point numbers
cout << "Please enter 5 floating-point numbers, all separtated by a space."<<endl;
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5;


// Store these numbers to the file
outputFile << num1 << endl;
outputFile << num2 << endl;
outputFile << num3 << endl;
outputFile << num4 << endl;
outputFile << num5 << endl;


// Close the file
outputFile.close();
cout << "Thank you!";

cin.ignore();
cin.get();

return 0; 
}
```

And I can find my text file which displays the numbers I entered just fine.

Then here's program 2:

```
// This program opens a file previously created, and displays
// the numbers and the sum of these numbers. 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Define Variables
ifstream inFile;
double num1; 
double num2;
double num3;
double num4;
double num5;


// Open the file from program 1
inFile.open("homework3.txt");

// Read and Display the Numbers
inFile >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5;
cout << num1 << endl << num2 << endl << num3 << endl << num4 << endl << num5 << endl;


inFile.close();

cin.ignore();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

I've omitted the part about finding the sum because it's not displaying correctly for me in the first place.

When I run this part I get

> -9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061
>   -9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O is something that often breaks, because computers aren't really great at guessing. Therefore, you really should check if an I/O operation succeeded:

```
if ( inFile >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5 )
{
  // Worked !
}
else
{
  // Failed ! Something is wrong, and C++ won't guess.
}
```

In fact, you should also check if the `open` succeeded. Is the file in the correct directory? Or is it perhaps in the directory for the previous exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably these are garbage values and make sure the file homework3.txt is correct and is opened correctly in the program.